# Resizing function not getting called in kendo grid

Tags: resize, kendo-grid

```
resizable: true,
columnResize: function (e) {
    core.common.grid.setColumnPrefs(e, _contracts)
},
```

Above "columnResize" function is not getting called, when I'm resizing the kendo columns.

Comment: Can you please show if there are any errors.

Comment: Please check also the version of your kendo if it covers the columnResize event.